# Export Links outlook

Tags: c#, vba, outlook

Is there a way to export only Links from outlook? I am trying to get only  the links from outlook to be able to feed them into linkchecker to help speed up the proofing process.

I have a folder where I receive proofing emails, and have been unable to figure out how  to extract just the links from the CSV export that I get.  I have tried to parse them out using regex in c#, using

```
Regex.Matches(csvcontent, @"\<([^(]*)\>")
```

but that seems to grab pretty much everything.  Is there a way to export just the links and the subject of an email from outlook through VBA, or something that can be done through some hidden menu somewhere?  I am using Outlook 2013, & VS 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) - will do what you need.

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(/* url */);
foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{

}
```